# Getting Error : XCode 8, iPhoneOS10.0.sdk

Tags: objective-c, clang, ios10, xcode8

After updating my xCode 7 to 8, I'm unable to compile my project.

> Apple Mach-O Linker Error
>
> > clang: error: no such file or directory:
> >     '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o'

Please let me know, What i've to do to solve this issue.

I already tried with removing derived data, cleaning project, and restart xCode.

Regards,

Comment: @Michael Rodrigues No not so far, I started work on xCode 7, Instead of wasting time on xCode 8.